# When should I use at-least-once delivery for Pub-Sub?

Tags: microservices, message-queue, publish-subscribe

After reading upon the difference between message-queue and pub-sub, I can't shake up the feeling that **having at-least-once delivery in pub-sub seems to be...unnecessary**

Per my understanding, one major difference between the two is

1. message-queue producer cares about the `enqueue()` status, that is if the message queue ever became unavailable, the producer will fail the request and surface the error to end user.
2. pub-sub publisher however is indifferent about whether the `PublishEvent()` succeeded or not. The event has already taken place, notifying pub-sub is like a side effect.

Given that the publisher calls pub-sub service in a fire-and-forget fashion, doesn't care if pub-sub server is up and running (I mean, since it's all decoupled, it doesn't even know if there's gona be any subscribers or not). we will never get 1:1 mapping between the events actually happened and event received by pub-sub, doesn't this implies at-most-once semantics is enough for pub-sub message delivery? everything is best effort

Comment: It's hard to understand what you really ask about. With "at-most-once" semantics you tolerate that you lose the data messages sometimes, is that really tolerated in your system? In most systems, we try to avoid data-losses.

Comment: I'm helping to develop a pub-sub like system, something along the lines of CDC (change Data Capture), and evaluating if its worth it to add at-least-once delivery. It will certainly increase the workload and I am looking for a justification.

Comment: That would be the only semantic I would look for, in such a system.